# How effective are "game programs" in interviews?

Tags: interview

I write business applications for a living.  Often, for whatever reason, an interviewer asks me to write up a program to solve some kind of game like problem.  I find this to be an inappropriate question for two main reasons:

1. Games often deal with constructs that are rarely used in business dev.  E.G. Multi-dimensional arrays. Store player locations on a checkerboard for instance. (Maybe it's just me, but I never use these things in biz)
2. My usual tools like BL/DL, ORMs and even designing the entities themselves don't translate well.  So I often end up with some goofy lookin code to start.  This is especially awkward if the interviewer is looking over your should to determine how "well you code".  Horribly uncomfortable, because...well I don't code like that...I don't write games for a living either.

Do you folks use them in your interviews and have they been effective for learning about a business apps dev?

Comment: I actually had the same sentiment... its even worse if its a game you can't remember the rules to...

Comment: I maintain that a good programming interview problem will relate to the subject at hand. If it's a financial company, I'd expect some sort of calculator, or accounting problem. If it's web development company, I'd expect a web app or backend data-access problem. If you spend a little time on interview questions, it's not too hard to come up with a short question that relates to what you do in some way.

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are rarely used in business dev? Ever pulled data from a database?

Comment: @bunglestink They pick a game like Checkers because 95% of people know the rules to Checkers.  If they don't then a 2 minute explanation is all they need for "gathering requirements".

Comment: @Ben - in .NET I use objects that can be easily iterated with loops.  If it's a multi-dim. array under teh covers, which that makes sense, it doesn't matter because I don't have to think about it.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Anything with good database access abastraction usually puts data in a nice multidimensional array when you SELECT, especially related data. Complex, related data really needs a multidimensional array. It might be $var[Location][Employee] instead of $var[1][2] like simple game grid arrays, but they're still very useful to know.

Comment: @Ben - I have written a couple of MVC3 applications used in production today. Had no need to use one.  It could be attributed to programming style, but still no.  I understand them, but because I rarely use them I have to think about it a lot more than I typically do in solving my "usual" problems.  As far as "related data in a multi-array", I create a class that represents an entity.  Each instance could represent a row in a table.  The instances are stored in a List<>.  I find this much more readable than multi-dim arrays.  Also easy to query with LINQ.

Comment: @BenBrocka Normally the multidimentional arrays come into play when you have to do historical data for similar types of objects, like prices for stocks.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey Depends on what you are doing and how fast you need to do it.  If you look at prices for 1000 items taken for 300 days that you need to do a statistical analysis on it's much easier to represent it as 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @Karlson also depends on what you use to get your data. CakePHP's DB functions give DB data in the form of $var[Index][PrimaryObject]([Related object])[Column], related object in case you have (potentially multiple) HABTM or other relationships. With relational data multidimensional arrays only make sense.

Comment: @BenBrocka The OP is a .NET developer where we have abstractions over arrays through IEnumerable<T> and any derivative therein where T is any given type including another IEnumerable<T>.  Querying of these lists is then done through LINQ.  Whilst I understand CakePHP may make heavy use of multi-dimensional arrays, to suggest they are the only way to effectively represent relational data within a language agnostic Domain Model is just plain wrong.

Comment: @DazLewis I shouldn't have implied they were the only effective way, but it is a common and very simple way to store and operate on relational data.

Comment: @maple_shaft: What's checkers. Is it something like [Draughts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts)

Comment: @maple_shaft: I got Monopoly on my last interview... a little bit more complex than checkers, especially when I haven't played it in probably 15 years...

Comment: As someone with fourteen years experience as a professional game programmer, I'd just like to point out that folks with experience in that industry wouldn't actually use multidimensional arrays to store the contents of a checkerboard (even though that's the intuitive approach).  Mapping the squares of a checkerboard to the indices of a single-dimensional array is just as easy, and is far better for performance.  :)

Comment: @bunglestink I am not so sure Monopoly is more complex than Checkers (American Draughts) as far as programatic difficulty goes.  The data and content however is somewhat more sophisticated and would lend itself easily to OO design principles.  If I were to ask about Monopoly I would be looking for the candidate to draw class diagrams.

Comment: @maple_shaft: You're definitely right in that Monopoly does lend itself to OO very well.  A lot better than something like checkers that can have an extremely simple backing model.  The challenge was more in that Monopoly has a ton of very specific rules that unless you played it recently, might not be on the top of your head.  I found myself spending more time trying to remember the specifics of Monopoly instead of working towards a clear goal. I did get the job though. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's one of those "We want to inteview like Google/Facebook/Amazon/etc" questions. Unless you're actually interviewing for a position at a game company, it wouldn't be useful to ask such questions. It would be more valuable to discuss/test something related to the problem domain of the company. For example, if I wanted you to write a web service to handle different formats of daily pricing feeds from 50+ different vendors I'd ask how you would approach it and have you sketch out, with some pseudo-code, how you would do it.

I did get asked gaming questions like this in an interview once, at a company developing a MMORPG. Sadly, I didn't get that job.

Comment: "We want to inteview like Google/Facebook/Amazon/etc but we don't know how to do it"

Answer (score 6):

I have used them in my interviews and I have been asked similar question in interviews.  Most of these questions are designed to gauge how well can you break a task into smaller components and how "neatly" for the lack of the better word can you make interactions between the components.

Normally I don't hover over the interviewee while he or she is doing the task but periodically I'd like to look at their work to gauge their train of thought.  This type of technique is also used to gauge how well a person can tune out the yell for "Get it done! Get it done! Get it done!" and actually focus to do the right thing.

Typical questions I saw was to design objects for the game of chess, checkers, tic-tac-toe or something similarly simple.  Writing implementation of methods is usually not required for things like this.

Comment: A "Swordfish" style interview?

Comment: No guns or girls involved but yes... :)

Comment: re-"This type of technique is also used to gauge how well a person can tune out the yell for "Get it done! Get it done! Get it done!" and actually focus to do the right thing." - I hope this doesn't simulate your work environment.  Have you considered throwing stuff at the interviewee, taking away their equipment as they work, blindfolding them?  You don't want weaklings!

Comment: That would be illegal in most place to do but on occasion it does emulate the work environment pretty well...

Comment: @psr - Hey, you never know when you might need an employee to baby sit and meet that hard deadline at the same time!

Answer (score 3):

I agree that trying to code while someone is staring over your shoulder is distracting.

My take on the game idea is that it allows you to get a feel for if the candidate can take a bizarre, off-the-cuff problem and come up with a workable solution to it.  It is not like they are asking you to have multiple moving sprites and arc vectors or anything that requires memorization of trigonometry.

They are asking you to do Checkers, because it is a simple game, simple set of rules, clear outcomes, and requires the use of a data structure more complicated than just an array.  The question is legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

Thats odd, I have never had that experience.  I get the exact opposite end of that spectrum. I usually get something like this "..we are experiencing this particular business/tech problem for these reasons, how would you go about solving it".  My interviews have always had much more practical questions.

When I interview people I tend to to go with asking about current work they are doing and then digging in deeper on areas that are relevant.  I usually get a very good sense of the persons ability and passion about what they do by digging in.  Are they getting excited about the problems they solved, are they offering up details about the challenges or am I having to dig them out etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most programming quizzes should focus on whether the applicant can program **AND** test logic/problem solving.  Programming and logic/problem solving are both very important.  It's not that easy to come up with a generic and challenging quiz, to get good programmers/problem solvers to work for you.

I think the game aspect of the interview is trying to test the logic/problem solving ability of the programmer, and in that regard, as long as the question is not too clever or obtuse, I think it is a reasonable method to test a programmer's problem solving ability.

That being said, quizzes are a rabbit hole few companies get right.

In general, a reasonable programmming quiz should be three parts:

1. Fizz buzz type of question to weed out applicants who can't program
2. A general question to test coding and logic/problem solving skills (this can be difficult to craft)
3. A speciic question to test industry skill and experience (for example, if database, then maybe some SQL type of questions, join tables, etc.)